# freemarker prb encoding in template

Tags: freemarker

I have  a template like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ContractRequest><SORequest/><Operator/><Contract>
<Engine_Type_Name>${Body.Contract.Engine.ENGINE_TYPE_NAME!""}</Engine_Type_Name>
```

I know that `Body.Contract.Engine.ENGINE_TYPE_NAME` = "Véhicule léger"
but freemarker puts it like this "VÃ©hicule lÃ©ger"

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you should view that output as UTF-8. If you don't want UTF-8 output, note that FreeMarker just sends its output into a `java.io.Writer`, and the encoding with a charset happens outside of FreeMarker. Also, you are outputting XML, so be sure that `<?xml ... encoding=... ?>` in the output specifies the correct charset too.